# mySql one to many relation table structures

Tags: mysql, join

Folks can you please give your suggestions for my question regarding mysql joins.

My Table structures:

`place table:
place_id     place_name            city

1            Hotel Golconda        Hyderabad 
2            Paradise Hotel        Hyderabad
3            Hotel Mayuri          Hyderabad`

place_tags
tag_id       tag_name
1            Valet Parking
2            Air Conditioned
3            Buffet
4            Bar
5            Family Dining

places_info Table:
place_id     tag_id
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             1
2             5
3             1
3             4

The above is all my tables which are containing the place names and address in places table, all the facilities of the restaurants in tags table and mapping of the facilities of each place in places_info table.

Is this my table structures are correct to get the places which had "Valet parking and Buffet". How can write a join query for this type of results to get.

Most Importantly we had millions of places in places table and also in the places_info table. How to achieve maximum performance with this type of table structure? Or shall I need to change the table structures?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This'd be the basic structure for "places with valet AND buffet":

```
SELECT place_id, COUNT(places_info) AS cnt
FROM place
LEFT JOIN places_info ON place.place_id = places_info.place_ID
    AND tag_id IN (1, 3)
                   ^^^^---- two tags: valet(1) + buffet(3)
GROUP BY place.place_id
HAVING cnt = 2
           ^^^---- must have both tags
```

For a places which have NEITHER of the tags, or only one, the count would come back `0`, or `1`, and get dumped by the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: having "GROUP BY" and "HAVING" clauses in the query, which was running on the tables having millions of records in both "places" and "places_info" tables will arise any performance issues? If Yes, How can I over come that?